# MERN : React router issue on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I deployed my MERN webapp on heroku yesterday.

Issue:

Example: When I click the login button, react router routes to < domain_name/login > but when I refresh the page OR hit enter on the address bar, it gives the below error :

```
Internal Server Error
```

Same goes for all the other client side routes except '/'.

Index.js file:

```
//including routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/address', require('./routes/address'));
app.use('/api/items', require('./routes/item'));
app.use('/api/orders', require('./routes/order'));


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
    });
};
```

React router config:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <Login />} />
      <Route exact path="/register" render={() => <Register />} />
      <Route exact path="/forgot-password" render={() => <ForgotPassword />} />
      <Route exact path="/password-reset/:id" render={(props) => <ResetPassword token={props} />} />
      <Route exact path="/admin" render={() => <Admin />} />
      <Route exact path="/orders" render={() => <MyOrders />} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer className="footer" />
  </AuthContextProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Folders

```
frontend/    models/        package.json       routes/    static.json
middleware/  node_modules/  package-lock.json  server.js
```

Comment: If it only happens on refresh/direct navigation to a URL that narrows it down to the `app.get('*', ...)` route. Have you done any debugging? Is there any more error information in the logs?

Comment: I checked the network tab in chrome, looks like it's not making any request. I've also set the NODE_ENV environment variable to 'production' in heroku. Can't seem to understand the issue here.